# Launch Metro style apps using powershell

Tags: uwp, windows-10, powershell-3.0, appx, start-process

I am trying to write a powershell script for windows 10 that will automatically launch a Metro-style app.
The `Start-Process` cmdlet seems like it should work, but I cannot get it to launch anything unless I provide a path to the `.exe`

For example, the following input works:

```
    Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe'
```

Unfortunately, Metro-style apps do not have an executable file. What file do I need to use to launch them?
If I wanted to launch Windows Store for example, how would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Store Apps can only be started by the shell. Try this:

```
explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

Comment: Also, you can this approach to launch your own UWP apps using the app id:  explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\18b72f48-axxx-xxxx-xxxx-903bd872921a_h65w5j3hw1x76!App

Comment: Nice, though it potentially gives you more flexibility to pass the `shell:` URI directly to `Start-Process`: `Start-Process shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`. Given the need to know the package family name, which includes the abstract publisher ID (`8wekyb3d8bbwe`) - `GetAppXPackage` can help with the discovery. However, it is generally easier to launch UWP applications via their specific URI protocol scheme, if possible; in the case at hand: `Start-Process ms-clock:`

Answer (score 4):

If the appx has registered a URI protocol scheme, you can launch it using that. For example, to launch windows store in Win8/Win10, use the following code:

```
    Start-Process ms-windows-store:
```

I was amazed at how little documentation there is for launching metro style apps.

Comment: `This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: According to Get-AppxPackage the name of windows store is "Microsoft.WindowsStore", where did you find "ms-windows-store" as the name?

Comment: it's not a name, but registered protocol. (such as in http: ) Only some Appx could be opened this way.

Comment: @Luke: The protocol names such as `ms-windows-store` are defined in the registry in subkeys of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId` - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58733061/45375) for details.

Answer (score 4):

You can locate the command to use with Start-Process by navigating here in the registry: Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId

Then expand ActivatableClassId, then the app, then in the CustomProperties folder look at the value for Name.

Start-Process must be run with PowerShell as is not recognised in CMD.

I used this to start the Windows Mail app.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>There's helpful information in the existing answers, but let me try to bring it all together, along with automated steps.

**This answer assumes the existence of an application-specific URI protocol**. **If that is not true for a given application, invoke it via the `shell:` URI scheme as shown in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39490206/45375)** (passing such a URI directly to `Start-Process` is sufficient; e.g.,

`Start-Process shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`). Note that you need to know the application family name, which includes the abstract publisher ID (`8wekyb3d8bbwe`);

`Get-AppXPackage` can help with the discovery - see below.</sup>

**Windows 8+** Metro-style apps (obsolete term) a.k.a **UWP applications / AppX packages / Microsoft Store applications** are **best launched by *URLs* using an *application-specific protocol scheme***:

For instance, the Calculator Windows 10 application defines two URL protocol names, `calculator` and `ms-calculator`, both of which can be used with a trailing `:` with `Start-Process`:

```bash
# Note the trailing ":"
Start-Process calculator: # Or: Start-Process ms-calculator:
```

Microsoft Edge supports protocol `microsoft-edge`, among others, so you can open a given URL, say `http://example.org` in Edge as follows:

```bash
Start-Process microsoft-edge:http://example.org
```

Note how in this case the `:` after the protocol name is followed by an *argument* to pass to the target application.

**Caveat**: As of PowerShell (Core) 7.2, many AppX applications cannot be launched with the `-Wait` and `-PassThru` parameters - see [GitHub issue #10996](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10996).

The **challenge is how to *discover* a given application's protocol names** by its application name (package name).

The following section discusses where this information can be found in the registry, and defines helper function `GetAppXUriProtocol`, which automates this discovery, allowing you to target applications by *wildcard expressions*, if the exact package name isn't known (which is typical).

For instance, you can find the protocol names for the Calculator application as follows:

```bash
# Find the protocol names supported by the Calculator application,
# by wildcard expression rather than full package name.
PS> Get-AppXUriProtocol *calculator*

PackageFullName                                            Protocols
---------------                                            ---------
Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1908.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe {calculator, ms-calculator}
```

That is, you can use `Start-Process calculator:` or `Start-Process ms-calculator:` to start the Calculator application.

If you just want information about an AppX package - which does *not* include the protocol names - use the standard [`Get-AppXPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackage) cmdlet; e.g.:

```bash
PS> Get-AppXPackage *calculator*
Name              : Microsoft.WindowsCalculator
Publisher         : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
...
```

---

#### Discovering an AppX application's URL protocol names:

The `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId` registry location has subkeys named for installed AppX packages, which specify the URL protocol names they support in the `Name` values of `ActivatableClassId\*\CustomProperties` subkeys.

The following function, `Get-AppXUriProtocol`, retrieves the protocol names associated with a given AppX application via the `Get-AppXPackage` cmdlet and registry lookups.

The function supports wildcard expressions, so you can search by part of a package name, such as an application's common name; e.g.
`Get-AppXUriProtocol *calc*`

**`Get-AppXUriProtocol` source code**:

```bash
function Get-AppXUriProtocol {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Gets the URI protocol names assocated with AppX packages on Windows 8 and above.

.DESCRIPTION
Given AppX package names or wildcard expressions, retrieves all associated
URI protocol names that can be used to launch these applications.

AppX is the package format for UWP applications typically distributed via
the Microsoft Store.

For instance, the protocol names associated with the Windows 10 Calculator
application are 'calculator' and 'ms-calculator', so you can use
Start-Process calculator: (note the appended ":") to launch it.

.PARAMETER PackageName
One or more package family names, full package names, or wildcard expresssions
matching either. 

.EXAMPLE
Get-AppXUriProtocol *calculator*

Outputs a [pscustomobject] instance such as the following:

PackageFullName                                            Protocols
---------------                                            ---------
Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1908.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe {calculator, ms-calculator}

#>
  [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $false)]
  [OutputType([pscustomobject])]
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
    [SupportsWildcards()]
    [string[]] $PackageName
  )
    
  begin {
    if ($env:OS -ne 'Windows_NT') { Throw "This command is supported on Windows only." }
  }

  process {
    # !! Even though Get-AppXPackage allegedly accepts -Name values from the pipeline
    # !! that doesn't work in practice.
    $packages = foreach ($name in $PackageName) { Get-AppXPackage -Name $name }
    foreach ($package in $packages) {
      $protocolSchemes = (Get-ChildItem registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\$($package.PackageFullName)\ActivatableClassId\*\CustomProperties).ForEach('GetValue', 'Name')
      [pscustomobject] @{ 
        PackageFullName = $package.PackageFullName
        Protocols       = $protocolSchemes
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyone showing up here looking because of WindowsTerminal, I wrote this function for my profile so I can elevate without moving my hands from the keyboard:

```
function term {
    $pkgName = (Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.WindowsTerminal).PackageFamilyName
    $Proc = @{
        FilePath = 'explorer.exe'
        ArgumentList = "shell:AppsFolder\$pkgName!App"
        Verb = 'RunAs'
    }
    Start-Process @proc
}
```

Comment: Nice, but you don't need `-FilePath explorer.exe`; instead, use `-FilePath "shell:AppsFolder\$pkgName!App"` directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the Windows SDK, there is an executable in there called:
`microsoft.windows.softwarelogo.appxlauncher.exe` which can be used to launch UWP apps.

The format is:
`microsoft.windows.softwarelogo.appxlauncher.exe <packageFamilyName>!App`

You can get the packageFamilyName of your app by looking at kayleeFrye_OnDeck's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a truly universal way to do this, but you can probably figure it out with a couple intermediary checks.

note: I hate using PowerShell, so pardon the weirdness of calling PS stuff from CMD

Step 1: Figure out what apps you have.

`powershell Get-AppXPackage` will generate the list of all of them. Let's say you specifically want to launch the Desktop App Converter so you can handle some Centennial patching while leveraging automation. So I'll query against the list of AppXs for something that might match using `findstr` to filter what comes back.

Step 2: Figure out if you already have the app you want

`powershell Get-AppXPackage | findstr /i Desktop`

While that gives me back numerous results, I can clearly see set of matches returned as:

```
Name              : Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter
PackageFullName   : Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
PackageFamilyName : Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

If I didn't get anythign like this back, the natural next step is to get the darned thing :) So for the next step, this could get tricky, and your mileage may vary:

Step 3: Find the location the app exists where you can actually call it:
Why am I doing this? Because if I try to run it from the path returned from the AppXPackage query, I'll get `"Access is denied."`

```
where DesktopAppConverter

C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\DesktopAppConverter.exe
```

You should then be able to take that resulting path and be able to run it from there.

Comment: Nice, but `Get-AppXPackage` directly supports wildcard expressions as package names, so you can do `Get-AppXPackage *Desktop*` Finding the file path isn't actually that helpful, because you can't launch an AppX app that way - use a URL scheme instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about `Get-AppXPackage` :) I think this answer is dated. The accepted answer seems to indicate that knowing the path used to be the only way to launch them at command-line. The URL scheme IIRC only works if developers supported it by manual inclusion instead of something automatically supported, but it may have changed in recent years. I do recall us needing to set the name desired for the URL scheme in the manifest file instead of it working automatically out of the box.

Comment: Thanks - hadn't considered that URI protocol names may not be mandatory / supported out of the box. The accepted answer doesn't actually use a path, it uses the `shell:` protocol scheme (though you don't necessarily need File Explorer for that, passing such a URI directly to `Start-Process` will do; e.g., `Start-Process shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`). For apps without their own URL protocol, is this obscure way really the only way to invoke them? Note that you need to know the application family name, which includes the abstract publisher ID (`8wekyb3d8bbwe`).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the *only* way nowadays, but it's a way that still seems to work. For example I can launch the iTunes store app by directly calling its executable in that directory ( `"C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\AppleInc.iTunes_nzyj5cx40ttqa\iTunes.exe"` ) , but that comes with a big-huge caveat about default permissions; IIRC you need to manually modify even an admin's permissions just to access the `WindowsApps` directories. I don't recall needing to change permissions to use this question's accepted answer for applicable apps.

Answer (score 0):

It's asserted the Metro style "App Store" apps don't have traditional executable files so I started digging a little and they do.  From an old skool Administrative cmd.exe try:

```
 dir "%ProgramW6432%\WindowsApps"
 dir "%ProgramW6432%\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1903.21.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"      Directory of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1903.21.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe

 04/30/2019  05:58 PM    <DIR>          .
 04/30/2019  05:58 PM    <DIR>          ..
 04/30/2019  05:58 PM            35,314 AppxBlockMap.xml
 04/30/2019  05:58 PM             3,860 AppxManifest.xml
 04/30/2019  05:58 PM    <DIR>          AppxMetadata
 04/30/2019  05:58 PM            11,296 AppxSignature.p7x
 04/30/2019  05:58 PM    <DIR>          Assets
 04/30/2019  05:58 PM         4,188,672 Calculator.exe
 04/30/2019  05:58 PM            95,744 CalculatorApp.winmd
 04/30/2019  05:58 PM           286,920 resources.pri
 04/30/2019  05:58 PM    <DIR>          WinMetadata
```

Helped me to find the exe for Ubuntu, `"%ProgramW6432%\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_1804.2019.522.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc\ubuntu1804.exe"`

Comment: Yes, there are executables, but you  _cannot always invoke them directly_; try `"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1908.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Calculator.exe"` from `cmd.exe`, for instance, which gives `Access is denied`. But the larger point is that even if that worked, it is obviously a very cumbersome method; if the app in question defines a URL protocol, you can simply do something like `Start-Process calculator:`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - and came up with the below code - note that the below code also provides the full line required as not all UWP programs use the '!App' suffix.. some are custom - this script pulls back the full package name and type - in my use case I generate a code for batch scripts in the last column - but this output could easily be updated to meet your requirements:

```
# Function to get the app ID for a given package name
function Get-AppId {
    param (
        [string]$PackageName
    )

    # Get the app package for the given package name
    $appPackage = Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $PackageName }

    if ($appPackage) {
        return $appPackage.PackageFamilyName
    } else {
        return $null
    }
}

# Get all installed UWP programs
$installedPackages = Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object { $_.IsFramework -eq $false }

if ($installedPackages.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "List of UWP programs with package name, app ID, and batch command:`n"

    # Generate a custom table with formatted columns
    $table = @()
    foreach ($app in $installedPackages) {
        $appName = $app.Name
        $appId = Get-AppId -PackageName $appName

        if ($appId) {
            $packageNameWithAppId = "$appName.$appId"

            # Get the app IDs from the app's manifest
            try {
                $ids = (Get-AppxPackageManifest $app -ErrorAction Stop).Package.Applications.Application.Id
            } catch {
                Write-Output "No IDs found for $($app.Name)" 
            }

            # Construct batch file command for each app ID
            foreach ($id in $ids) {
                $line = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Name = $appName
                    "Package Name" = $packageNameWithAppId
                    "App ID" = $id
                    "BatchFileCommand" = "start explorer.exe `shell:AppsFolder\$($appId)!$($id)"
                }
                $table += $line
            }
        }
    }

    # Output the formatted table
    $table | Format-Table -AutoSize 

} else {
    Write-Host "No installed UWP programs found."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @mklement0 mentioned above:

> Caveat: As of PowerShell (Core) 7.2, many AppX applications cannot be launched with the -Wait and -PassThru parameters - see GitHub issue #10996.

To work around that I have been using a work around. I was told I should probably post it here. But I don't have enough reputation for a comment.

```
Start-Process calculator:
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Get-Process CalculatorApp | Wait-Process
Write-Warning "App Closed."
```

This will start Calculator using Start-Process. Grab the Process ID after it starts. Then wait until the App closes.