# How can I open a new instance of Windows Terminal from Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-terminal

I'm trying to configure a profile in Windows Terminal that opens a new Windows Terminal window.

When I try to start `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_0.4.2382.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsTerminal.exe` there is an access denied error.

This is because the Windows Terminal is a Windows-Store-App (aka. Modern Windows App, aka. Mono App).

How can I start the WindowsTerminal.exe from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows Terminal can be launched simply by "wt.exe".

[The proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWuUx.png)

Comment: Nice, thanks! I marked this as the accepted answer since it provides the information that I was looking for. It can be combined with my answer below to add the correct icon.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Open Windows-Store-Apps from the command line**

I found this answer on how to open Windows-Store-Apps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39490206/10069673

Example:
`explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`

**2. Find the name of the app**

- start WindowsTerminal
- open the TaskManager (`ctrl+shift+esc`)
- expand `Windows Terminal (Preview)`
- right click on `OpenConsole.exe` and select "Open file location"

File location:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_0.4.2382.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Final command (remove version number in directory name):

```
explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

**3. Configure Windows Terminal profile**

This is how I configured my profile.

- `commandline` is set to the command from step 2.
- `icon` is set to the Windows Terminal logo from the app's directory
- `name` is self explanatory

We don't need to configure any other properties since this profile just starts a new instance of Windows Terminal with a new tab of the default profile.

```
{
    "commandline": "explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App",
    "icon": "ms-appx:///Images/LockScreenLogo.scale-100.png",
    "name": "Terminal"
},
```

**4. Final result**
[image: Open Windows Terminal from Windows Terminal]

Answer (score 0):

The simple way in **2020**

#### Approach 1:

- Press `WIN key` + `R`
- Type `wt -d D:\SomeDirectory` and this will open up the default shell present in the settings.json with that directory

#### Approach 2:

- Go to the desired folder using the File Explorer.
- In the address bar of the desired folder type `wt -d .`

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/620#issuecomment-642267289